# JavaScript identify the page is RTL or LTR?

Tags: javascript, html

How to identify the HTML page is RTL or LTR direction, I wanted to dynamically change some classes using javascript based on the direction of the page using

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kidofetaci/1/edit?html,output — The assumption that a **page** will be RTL or LTR is not generally safe (and if you control the pages then you should be able to determine which direction and which classes to use server wide without resorting to client side code … not that you should use classes because we have the `dir` attribute and you can write CSS with attribute selectors)

Answer (score 0):

By Default HTML is LTR with dir attribute which specified in html tag. If you want to specify the direction for a element use 'dir' arrtibute.

Syntax for alter the direction advanced:

```
var currentWritingDirection = elementNodeReference.dir;
elementNodeReference.dir = newWritingDirection;
```

[

```
var parg = document.getElementById("paraXX");
parg.dir = "rtl";
// change the text direction on a paragraph identified as "paraXX"
```

]